# Reference typing file from a global folder or absolute from the project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I know that TypeScript is new, but just playing around with it.

I have tried converting a few .js files that uses jQuery and for intellisense to work I need to reference the jquery.d.ts file in the top like

```
 /// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

That's fine, but then you also need to have the file in the same directory. What i want is to reference typing file globally, instead of relative to the file, so if I move the js file, I don't have to correct the reference path to the typing file.

Is it possible to make them relative to the solution or maybe have it placed in a global folder that is automatically loaded.

I use the web essentials for visual studio 2012, so i get preview and other nice features.

Hope there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Reference Directives" section of [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx), it says the following is supported:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/ScriptFile4.js" />
```

However, I couldn't get it working for typescript files. I guess it's not supported for typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Global or project relative paths are not supported. There's a feature request for it here:

**Absolute root path for reference / import**

https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1414